# How to getLocation() in JPanel of JLabel that has been dynamically added?

Tags: java, swing, components, location, dynamic

I have created a number of JLabels dynamically and have added them to a JPanel with the following code (code should be enough to understand the problem I hope!).

```
    JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();
    map = new HashMap<Integer,JLabel>();
    vec = new Vector<JLabel>();
    for(int i = 0; i<getCount();i++){ // getCount() returns int
               JLabel label = new JLabel(getItemText(i)); // getItemText() returns String
               map.put(i, label);
               vec.add(label);
               textPanel.add(map.get(i));
    }
```

Now I am trying to access the Location of these labels but get nothing but `java.awt.Point[x=296,y=63]` for them when trying to access them via the following code.

```
System.out.println("Component position [1]: " +
textPanel.getComponent(1).getLocationOnScreen());
```

I get the same position for **all** Components, not just for the one.

Also (more importantly) I get the position `java.awt.Point[x=0,y=0]` for the following code.

```
System.out.println("Position of Component 1: " + map.get(1).getLocation());
```

I'm guessing this is to do with the fact that the JLabels are created dynamically. I *really* need to create them dynamically, however, and also *really* need to be able to get their Location via `getLocation()`.

Please help! Perhaps there is another way to create them or a way to access their Location(s) differently?

Comment: *"code should be enough to understand the problem I hope!"*  An [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) is generally enough to explain a problem.  Or at least to compile, run and see the problem.

Comment: @baphomet13: out of curiosity, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Ihballoti: I'm trying to display a row of Strings so that I can access the Location of every word ("token"). The word Strings are what I get with the `getItemText()` method. Ultimately I want to draw constituent trees on top of the JLabels. If anybody has a better way, please shoot 'em my way :). Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create a component it has a default location of (0, 0);

Adding a component to a panel does NOT change this location.

After adding all the labels to the panel you need to do:

```
panel.revalidate();
```

This will invoke the layout manager used by the panel and each label will then be assigned a proper location based on the rules of the layout manager.

Comment: You might need to `revalidate()` the parent component too, depending on your UI design.

Comment: @camickr: Thank you very much indeed! I forgot all about `revalidate()`ing...
@Alexey Ivanov: Thanks, `validate()`ing the `getContentPane()` has finally got it to work. 
Thanks both, you have saved me hours of work! Next time, @Andrew Thompson, I will remember to give a SSCCE. Promise :).

Answer (score 4):

Here is an SSCCE.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class WhereIsMyComponent {

    public static void showComponentLocations(Container parent) {
        Component[] all = parent.getComponents();
        System.out.println("Show locations of children..");
        for (Component c : all) {
            System.out.println(c.getLocation());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String msg = "Hello World!";
        final JPanel p = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        for (int ii=0; ii<6; ii++) {
            p.add(new JLabel(msg));
        }

        ComponentListener cl = new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent ce) {
                showComponentLocations(p);
            }
        };

        p.addComponentListener(cl);

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Where Is My Component?");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(p);
        f.pack();
        f.setSize(400,300);
        f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

#### Typical output

```
Show locations of children..
java.awt.Point[x=16,y=5]
java.awt.Point[x=89,y=5]
java.awt.Point[x=162,y=5]
java.awt.Point[x=235,y=5]
java.awt.Point[x=308,y=5]
java.awt.Point[x=162,y=26]
Show locations of children..
java.awt.Point[x=16,y=5]
java.awt.Point[x=89,y=5]
java.awt.Point[x=162,y=5]
java.awt.Point[x=235,y=5]
java.awt.Point[x=308,y=5]
java.awt.Point[x=162,y=26]
Show locations of children..
java.awt.Point[x=26,y=5]
java.awt.Point[x=99,y=5]
java.awt.Point[x=172,y=5]
java.awt.Point[x=26,y=26]
java.awt.Point[x=99,y=26]
java.awt.Point[x=172,y=26]
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Thank you! I will use this as example to create SSCCE in the future!